# How I can connect two cmd Windows ? [batch files]

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, triggers, command

I want to develop a little Game.
And for this, I want to connect two windows.

For example: I do something in the first window and the second window is waiting for a certain command.
If I write this command, the command will trigger an action in window 2.
But I don't know how I do this.

Answer (score 1):

if it's only "wait for a certain command", the rarely known command [waitfor](http://ss64.com/nt/waitfor.html) might help. It works not only on the same computer but also across the network (both computers have to be on the same network, so it doesn't work over internet).

On one window (batchfile) you wait for a certain signal with `waitfor MySignal`. The batchfile will then pause, until it receives that exact signal.

On the other window, you can send that signal with `waitfor /SI MySignal`.

The name for the signal can be any string you choose.
There are some more options, see `waitfor /?`

Answer (score 0):

Let's have a directory

```
root/
    game1.bat
    game2.bat
    1
```

You may try to use a file which will have a specific name for each of your windows and you'll check the name of the file. If the name isn't what is required by one window, then use an infinite loop that will check for that name while your user will see only "wait for your turn" or something similar.

At the first run of your file set an identifier for each window (manually, use two files) such as `1` and `2`. If player1 is on the turn, then your file will be named `1` and player2 will have an infinite loop which will be checking for the name of that file with some text visible to player2 while he waits.

After player1 ends his turn, he'll rename the file to `2` and begin the stage in which he'll wait for a turn, checking the name of file from a loop.

Example:

```
set ID = 1 or set ID = 2
if exist 1 (
    if %ID%==1 (
        rem player1 is playing
    )
) else (
    if %ID%==2 (
        rem player1 waits, player2 is playing
    )
)
```